# How to change database version of a Google Cloud SQL (Second Gen) instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a large Google Cloud SQL (Second Gen) instance, and I would like to upgrade my database version from MySQL 5.6 to 5.7. But `database version` option is disabled on the edit instance form.

Why it is disabled, do i have to create a new instance then export and import existing database? My database is too large, and it will be a long downtime.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [Cloud SQL Migration docs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/migrating#migrating), the only way to migrate versions is to export your data, and re-import into a new instance. The documentation mentions going from 5.5 to 5.6, but I would believe that going 5.6 to 5.7 would follow the same procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Minor version upgrades to MySQL through Google Cloud now appears to be supported, though only through API calls:
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/upgrade-minor-db-version#gcloud

The pertinent section if using the `gcloud` CLI:

```
gcloud sql instances patch $INSTANCE_NAME --database-version=$DATABASE_VERSION
```

Substitute your instance name for the `$INSTANCE_NAME` variable, and your target database version in place of `$DATABASE_VERSION`.

There appear to be two REST APIs also available - see the documentation for details.